# Is there any way to embed any website into other website in html?

Tags: html, embed

I build a Survey Application using ReactJs, Now I am creating other application and trying to embed the Survey form (i.e. created by my survey application), but it is displaying error

**Refused to display 'https://www.example.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.**

So Basically I am trying to create google form like form and want to embed it into any application so that any user register on my survey application, create their form and embed it into any application using iframe.

if I am using localhost:3000 then I write

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:3000/"></iframe>
```

it is runing fine, but when i try this

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/"></iframe>
```

then It is giving me the error.

Can someone help me to do this?

Comment: If you built or manage the server the application is running on you can set your **X-Frame-Options** to allow content from the domain where the form is hosted.

Comment: @KrisSinclair How can I do that?

Comment: What web server are you using to host your React app?